# Sql Server mostrar codigo repetidos que solo esten en dos o mas contratos

Tags: sql, datatables, group-by

Estimados buenas tardes.

Estoy tratando de encontrar la consulta que solo permita mostrar los codigos repetidos con dos o más contratos distintos.

```
Codigo   Contrato
000001   104030
000001   104030
000005   104030
000005   105077
000001   104017
000005   105077
000003   105077
000005   104030
```

Puedo definir cuales son los repetidos usando:

```
SELECT Codigo, Contrato
FROM tabla1
GROUP BY Codigo
HAVING count(*) > 1

Codigo   Contrato
000001   104030
000005   104030
000003   105077
```

Pero necesito obtener:

```
Codigo   Contrato
000001   104030
000001   104017
000005   104030
000005   105077
```

Osea los Códigos repetidos pero CON DOS O MAS Contratos DIFERENTES

De ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: O sea tenes una consulta que te devuelve los codigos.. entonces ya lo resolviste.. usa eso como entrada de otra consulta que muestre solo esos codigos ;).. (spoiler, tenes que usar in, y adentro del in esta consulta)

Comment: La consulta debe ser formulada a los registros repetidos pero con dos o mas contratos diferentes. Si uso IN no tengo la referencia del contrato a incluir

Comment: Ahora te pongo una respuesta... pero tu respuesta es usando un in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otra solución:

Primero excluir las filas cuyas columnas Codigo y Contrato tienen los mismos valores (filas "duplicadas"), luego contar la cantidad de filas que quedaron con el mismo Codigo (pero distinto Contrato), y por último filtrar las filas cuya cantidad > 1 (hay mas de una fila con el mismo Codigo pero distinto Contrato).

```
SELECT Codigo, Contrato
FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Codigo) AS cantidad
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tabla1) AS sqd) AS sqc
WHERE cantidad > 1;
```

Comment: Excelente, soluciona el requerimiento. Muchas Gracias =)

Comment: De nada @Juanpiro!

Answer (score 1):

Si esta consulta:

```
SELECT Codigo
FROM tabla1
GROUP BY Codigo
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Te devuelve los codigos a seleccionar, entonces podes usarla en un `in` para obtener el resto de los registros que queres:

```
select Codigo, Contrato
from tabla1
where codigo IN (
    SELECT Codigo
    FROM tabla1
    GROUP BY Codigo
    HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: El resultado serán todos los Codigos Repetidos, la idea es SOLO mostrar los repetidos pero que tengan dos o más Contratos DIFERENTES:

Comment: @Juanpiro ok. no tengo un fiddle para probar esto.. y no recuerdo si podias poner en el having una columna que no estuviera en el group by, pero si no, having count(contrato) deberia ser la solucion...

Comment: Entiendo que debería ser `HAVING count(DISTINCT Contrato)` para tener la cuenta de  los contratos distintos y por último un `group by Codigo, Contrato`